# InsertRecord Method i have to convert it for SQLLOCALDB help required

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I am converting a SQL Server CE `insertRecord` method to SQL Server LocalDB and I am blocked with below mentioned two lines, I can't find any alternative for this.

Could you please help me?

```
using (SqlCeResultSet rs = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable)) {
       SqlCeUpdatableRecord ceRec = rs.CreateRecord();
}
```

Comment: what you mean by stuck ?

Comment: A `SqlCeResultSet` is something like an ADO `Recordset`.  You can either use that or else use ADO.NET and use a `SqlDataAdapter` to populate a `DataTable` and save changes back to the database.  You can also call `ExecuteNonQuery` on a `SqlCommand` to insert a record directly.